# Read line by line and replace string

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed

I currently have a problem that I need to read a file line by line.

After I read it line by line there are some commands in which I have to change a specific string.(In my case, I have to make a script that changes all the passwords into hash value)

Here is a sample input

```
hostName=TEST123
hostIpAddr=TEST123
hostUserName=test112
hostPassword=test146

HostName=11.111.111
HostIpAddr=12.12.121
UserName=UseR1
Password=UsEr1
```

I only tried to change the second occurence of Password with this code.

```
passNew=grep 'Password' test.file | awk -F= '{print $2}' | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:wtf
passStr=grep 'Password' test_dev.param | awk -F= '{print $2}'
sed 13,/$passStr/{s@$passStr@$passNew@} test.file > test1.file
```

Any help I cant get so I can loop up? and convert every occurence of passwords to hash?

The sample output must be:

```
hostName=TEST123
hostIpAddr=TEST123
hostUserName=test112
hostPassword=JfsjeoOf3001=

HostName=11.111.111
HostIpAddr=12.12.121
UserName=UseR1
Password=Fkjdslkjqksnlkc491/+FDSJLK=
```

Comment: If security is an issue it is suggested by the man page of openssl do not use `-pass:password` as the password could be easily seen by anyone (e.g. using `ps -ef`). Use `-env:var` or `-file:pathname` instead to read the password from an environment variable or from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One-liner `awk`:

```
awk -F'=' -v q="'" '/Password/{ cmd="echo " q $2 q" | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:wtf"; cmd | getline $2 }1' OFS="=" yourfile
```

More readable `awk` version:

```
#!/bin/awk -f                           

BEGIN {
        FS=OFS="=";
        q="'";
}

/Password/ {
        cmd="echo " q $2 q " | openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:wtf";
        cmd | getline $2
}1
```

Run:

```
$ awk -f script.awk inputfile > outputfile
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS=OFS="="` - Setting Input/Output Field Separator as `=`.
- `/Password/ { ... }` - Doing the password hash conversion only for lines containing a pattern `Password`.
- Next, Making a command.
- `cmd | getline $2` - Executing the command and storing output in `$2`.
- `1` - true value. In that case, `awk`'s default behaviour is to print the current line (`{print $0}`).

Comment: so where will I put the input file from the more readable awk version? @sat

Comment: Like this: `awk -f script.awk inputfile`

Comment: Actually this fails if the password contains any of the `'`, backtick, `"` or backslash characters and does not provide good result if it contains double spaces. If the Password value contains `$(...)` characters it is even possible to launch any program.

Comment: The above mentioned problems could be avoided if the `here-strings` (`<<<word`) was used instead of `echo word|...`. Also more effective as avoids a `fork` of [tag:bash].The cmd part could be rewritten as: `cmd="openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:wtf <<<'\''" $2 "'\''";`

Comment: Hmmm. Also there is a problem if the password contains `=` character. And it cannot be solved by the solution mentioned above. Only using `sub` or `match` functions and part the input string with `substr`.

Comment: There is another issue with this solution! [tag:Awk] always opens a pipe to `openssl` for each password line, but actually never closes them. So after a while (on my Linux it is 1020. See `getconf OPEN_MAX`.) the test awk reports `awk: (FILENAME=- FNR=1021) fatal: cannot open pipe `echo 1020' (Too many open files)`. The solution is simple. After `getline` a `close(cmd)` has to be added.
Anyway for a big file, which contains more then 1000 password lines the pure [tag:bash] solution is slower the the [tag:awk].

Answer (score 0):

For small files I do not recommend to use any non [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) builtin utilities. Openssl is the only one is needed. Here is a sample code:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

cat << INPUT >inputfile
hostName=TEST123
hostIpAddr=TEST123
hostUserName=test112
hostPassword=test146

HostName=11.111.111
HostIpAddr=12.12.121
UserName=UseR1
Password=UsEr1
INPUT

while read -r f; do
    if [[ $f =~ ([^=]*Password=)(.*) ]]; then
        #echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}, ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
        new=$(openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -a -salt -pass pass:wtf <<< ${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
        f="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}$new"
    fi
    echo "$f"
done < inputfile
```

Output is:

```
hostName=TEST123
hostIpAddr=TEST123
hostUserName=test112
hostPassword=U2FsdGVkX18HCG/khxco1skg2v9UTcXjqPPda0g3tuI=

HostName=11.111.111
HostIpAddr=12.12.121
UserName=UseR1
Password=U2FsdGVkX1/8c3O8m6vTnU75bs4EBCGLKmfL1PWxk4M=
```

I hope this helps a bit.

In the `while` loop it reads all lines and tries to math with the pattern shown in `[[...]]`. If match found, then convert the password part and puts to an env.var. And prints the found Password tag with the new password.

The `-r` option disables the escape meaning of `\`, so it can be used in the password string.

<s>Problem can appear if the password contains the string 'Password=', but this is a rare case. If this can happen use another if, to check the case. As I know RE used by `[[...]]` does not have non-greedy regex option as [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) has.</s> **Solved**

Comment: what if the input is stored in a file?

Comment: @Benson: As you can see, input is stored in the `inputfile`. The loop reads that file. The `cat` part is just to create the test input file. Not needed in the real code.